# Sending bearer token to autorest typescript client

Tags: typescript, autorest

I am using **autorest** to generate TypeScript clients for accessing RESTful web services. All REST api looks for bearer token for authentication but I didn't find a way to pass token to autogenerated TypeScript clients.

I did try searching autorest documentation. It looks like I need to use ServiceClientCredentials but I didn't find any sample code.

Does anyone know how to use ServiceClientCredentials in TypeScript?

I use the following command to generate TypeScript clients

```
autorest --input-file=restapi.json --typescript --output-folder=./output --package-name="test-api" --package-version="0.1.0" --generate-metadata=true --add-credentials=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to create an object of `TokenCredentials` and pass it in autogenerated client

```
// Create token
  const tokenCredentials: TokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(
    'some token'
  );

  // Add token and server url to service instance
  const service: AutoGeneratedSvc = new AutoGeneratedSvc(
    tokenCredentials,
    'server url'
  );
```